# How to install custom annotation on the map depending on the zoom

Tags: swift, mapkit

1) I need to set a custom annotation, depending on the zoom on the map, they will be placed throughout the track on the map. (Arrows showing the direction).

my code

```
   class customPin: NSObject, MKAnnotation {
    var coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D
    var title: String?
    var subtitle: String?

    init(pinTitle:String, pinSubTitle:String, location:CLLocationCoordinate2D) {
        self.title = pinTitle
        self.subtitle = pinSubTitle
        self.coordinate = location
    }
}


    func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
    if annotation is MKUserLocation {
        return nil
    }

    let annotationView = MKAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: "customannotation")
    annotationView.image = UIImage(named:"mov_on_2")
    annotationView.canShowCallout = true
    return annotationView
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way I have found to do this is to determine the distance of screen width shown by the map. You can do that using the mapView's span like so in the maps `regionDidChangeAnimated`:

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, regionDidChangeAnimated animated: Bool) {

    // Get the span and the center coordinate of the mapview
    let span = mapView.region.span
    let center = mapView.centerCoordinate
    // Create two points on the left and right side of the region
    let rightSide = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: center.latitude + (span.latitudeDelta / 2), longitude: center.longitude)
    let leftSide = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: center.latitude - (span.latitudeDelta / 2), longitude: center.longitude)

    // Calculate the distance between these two points (don't forget to convert to meters!)
    let distance = calculateDistanceBetween(firstLoc: leftSide, secondGeoPoint: rightSide) * 1609.34

    // Switch case the distance to handle zooming logic
    switch distance {
    case _ where distance < 1000:
        // Handle logic for if the on screen width distance is < 1000 meters
    case _ where distance < 5000:
        // Handle logic for if the on screen width distance is < 5000 meters
    default:
        // Handle logic for if the on screen width distance is > 5000 meters
    }
}
```

Where the distance between any two GPS coordinates can be found using:

```
// Calculates the distance between two locations, returned in miles
func calculateDistanceBetween(firstLoc: CLLocationCoordinate2D, secondLoc: CLLocationCoordinate2D) -> Double {
    // Convert lat's and long's into radians
    let firstLatR = firstLoc.latitude * Double.pi / 180
    let firstLongR = firstLoc.longitude * Double.pi / 180
    let secondLatR = secondLoc.latitude * Double.pi / 180
    let secondLongR = secondLoc.longitude * Double.pi / 180
    // Calculate and return the distance
    return 2 * 3963.1 * asin((pow(sin((secondLatR - firstLatR) / 2), 2) + cos(firstLatR) * cos(secondLatR) * pow(sin((secondLongR - firstLongR) / 2), 2)).squareRoot())
}
```

It is worth noting that the above equation assumes the earth is a perfect sphere. This should be more than accurate enough for your application. 
The problem with finding a true "zoom" level for the map is that the map distance of on screen width (Distance of a degree longitude) [changes depending on your latitude](https://www.thoughtco.com/degree-of-latitude-and-longitude-distance-4070616).